# How do I find my IP Address from the command line?

Tags: terminal, network

I know you can do `ifconfig | grep inet`, but that shows you several IPv4 addresses. How do I get the specific one for SSHing et al?

Comment: What you are looking for is not your Mac IP address but the **public** IP address your ISP attributed to the Internet interface of your router.

Comment: Need to change title for public IP address.

Comment: This worked for me : > curl ipecho.net/plain; echo

Comment: You should either clarify your question, i.e. you want to know internal IP in your local network or change the accepted answer, because none of the answers give you an option to get an external IP, but a few comments do.

Comment: @alturium you should make it an answer, because it IS the answer to the question. Just add a command to get internal IP as well.

Comment: @JShoe, can you confirm whether you wanted the internal or external IP address?  That would help make this all of the answers below clearer: some show you how to get internal addresses, while others show external.

Comment: osascript -e 'return IPv4 address of (get system info)'

Comment: Building on other ansvers: `ipconfig getifaddr $(route -n get default | awk '$1=="interface:" { print $2 }')` - get the address of the interface handling the default route. I don't have enough reputation to add this to an answer.

Comment: Also, to list all IP's, and which one is the default route: `for INF in $(ipconfig getiflist); do IPADDR=$(ipconfig getifaddr ${INF}) ; [ "${INF}" = "$(route -n get default | awk '$1 == "interface:" { print $2 }')" ] && DEF=" (*)" ; [ -n "${IPADDR}" ] && echo ${INF}: ${IPADDR}${DEF:-''} ; DEF="" ; done`.  Still missing rep to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 478, accepted):

#### Local IP address

**For wireless:** Use `ipconfig getifaddr en1`

**For ethernet:** Use`ipconfig getifaddr en0`.

*`ipconfig getifaddr en0` is default for the Wi-Fi network adapter*

#### Public IP address

```
dig -4 TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com
```

Output, e.g.:

```
172.79.136.120
```

**Command explanation**

The command you provided, `dig -4 TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com`, is a command-line instruction that uses the `dig` utility to perform a DNS (Domain Name System) lookup. Let's break down the components of the command:

- `dig`: `dig` stands for "domain information groper," and it is a command-line tool commonly available on Unix-like systems for querying DNS servers.
- `-4`: This option specifies that the command should use IPv4 protocol for the DNS lookup. It ensures that the query is sent using IPv4 instead of IPv6.
- `TXT`: This indicates the type of DNS record being requested. In this case, the command is asking for the TXT record.
- `+short`: This option is used to display only the relevant information from the DNS response, providing a concise output.
- `o-o.myaddr.l.google.com`: This is the hostname used for the DNS lookup. It is a special hostname that Google uses to provide information about the IP address from which the DNS query originates.
- `@ns1.google.com`: This specifies the DNS server to which the query is sent. In this case, it is set to `ns1.google.com`, which is one of Google's public DNS servers.

When you run this command, it queries the `ns1.google.com` DNS server for the TXT record associated with `o-o.myaddr.l.google.com`. The response will contain the TXT record, which typically includes information about the IP address of the client making the DNS query. The `+short` option ensures that only the relevant information is displayed, making it easier to read the output.

Comment: This shows my internal (to my router) IP address (e.g. 192.168.1.xxx), not the external IP address. (As do most of the other answers below.)

Comment: Didn't work for me :(

Comment: `ifconfig` shows all of the interfaces and their IPs

Comment: echo External IP: `curl -s http://checkip.dyndns.org/ | sed 's/[a-zA-Z<>/ :]//g'`

Comment: It has changed for years, 'ipconfig getifaddr en0' is default for wifi interface

Comment: @JShoe mentioned ipconfig. So i guess he's not on windows. Linux or mac maybe? Did you mean ifconfig? Anyway, this didn't work for me.

Comment: This is totally wrong for all MacBooks connecting on anything other than built-in Ethernet (modern macbooks do  not even have it built in). This ONLY tells you the addres at en1 or en2 and does not determine which is active and even that can be hard with modern multi-homing.

Comment: ipconfig getifaddr en2 works for me

Comment: when you don't know which interface you're on: `ifconfig -l | xargs -n1 ipconfig getifaddr`

Comment: See the bash script answer below for a better solution.  You don't always know if you're on wifi or ethernet, or you might be using an interface that's not `en0` or `en1`.  For example, I have a 10G thunderbolt NIC that for some reason is on `en14`.  The solution below from @Brad Parks covers all this!

Comment: @grigb you should make it an answer, because it IS the answer to the question. Just add a command to get internal IP as well.

Comment: `ipconfig getifaddr en0 ` returns empty string

Comment: @ShreevatsaR if you are behind a router, it is usually performing NAT, so your computer will not know "its" external IP, because technically it is assigned to the router, not the computer itself. therefore, you cannot get your external IP address without creating some **connection** to retrieve that data (e.g. using `curl`, `dig`, `wget`). every solution mentioning local-only tools (e.g. `ifconfig`, `netstat`, `hostname`) will only give you your machine's internal IP.

Comment: if dig is not installed install using (ubuntu)
sudo apt install dnsutils

Comment: `curl -s api.infoip.io/ip 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Now `getifaddr en0 ipconfig` works too

Comment: In my experience, wireless is `en1` on my iMac probably since it has an ethernet port which must be `en0`, whereas on my Macbook Air, `en0` is the wireless since it's the first (and only) interface

Answer (score 182):

The following works for me on 10.8 and on 10.10 Yosemite.

```
ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

If you find the above gives you more than one answer, save the following to a script, and run it instead

#### ip_address.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dumpIpForInterface()
{
  IT=$(ifconfig "$1") 
  if [[ "$IT" != *"status: active"* ]]; then
    return
  fi
  if [[ "$IT" != *" broadcast "* ]]; then
    return
  fi
  echo "$IT" | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'
}

main()
{
  # snagged from here: https://superuser.com/a/627581/38941
  DEFAULT_ROUTE=$(route -n get 0.0.0.0 2>/dev/null | awk '/interface: / {print $2}')
  if [ -n "$DEFAULT_ROUTE" ]; then
    dumpIpForInterface "$DEFAULT_ROUTE"
  else
    for i in $(ifconfig -s | awk '{print $1}' | awk '{if(NR>1)print}')
    do 
      if [[ $i != *"vboxnet"* ]]; then
        dumpIpForInterface "$i"
      fi
    done
  fi
}

main
```

Comment: The should be the accepted answer in my opinion since it doesn't require any wired vs. wireless specification.

Comment: @ErikNomitch except it gives me 2 with this answer

Comment: Ah, I retract then. @ZachLysobey

Comment: this is the best overall approach but one needs to sometimes do a bit more grepping before awk to get the right answer and the right answer might vary.

Comment: I added a script that should hopefully address this issue.. fyi !

Comment: Can confirm this solution works great.  I have multiple interfaces all with valid local IPs, but this solution properly returns the IP for the primary interface (that is, the interface used to route traffic to the wider net)

Comment: Would you amend your script to return an external IP for the primary interface as well?

Comment: For some reason can't get it to work on oh-my-zsh...

Comment: Did you keep the first line, the shebang the same (```#!/usr/bin/env bash```) ? If you didnt, it wont work, I dont think. It's ok to run a bash script from zsh (I use oh-my-zsh myself), so you dont need to change that top line

Comment: This does not guarantee giving the public IP.  It gave me my internal IP addresses.  :(

Comment: gotta love the overachievers of the world - nice work

Comment: Great script! NB! The fallback using `ifconfig -s` is not available on MacOS. Can be replaced with `ipconfig getiflist` --> A space separated list of interfaces.

Comment: adding the "see also" for the back link: https://superuser.com/a/627581/38941

Answer (score 163):

Typing `curl ifconfig.me` in Terminal will give your public IP address

Comment: Be advised that this works by actually making a network request to the Internet site "ifconfig.me". (It's not a purely "local" solution.)

Comment: Easier and works, Thanks

Answer (score 42):

I've got this set up in an .aliases dotfile for frequent ip lookup:

```
alias ip="dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"
alias localip="ipconfig getifaddr en0"
```

Comment: For me, the localip option there doesn't work anymore, but this does: `ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: This is the best answer: While `dig` does reach outside of your machine, it is a domain name resolver, which means its main function is precisely to match domain name to IP address.  In this case, it is your own IP address, of course.

Comment: the ip alias doesn't seem to be working (I'm on OSX Catalina). This one does: `curl -s http://ipecho.net/plain; echo`

Comment: Running the *dig* command on macOS Monterey produces no output.
Running the *curl -s* command does seem to work.

Answer (score 29):

You can do the following:

Type `ifconfig` or `ifconfig -a`. This command shows you the list of interfaces along with their IP and MAC addresses (the latter one only if applicable). You can also type `ifconfig en0` or `ifconfig en1` for the configuration of a particular interface only (as someone said in their answers, en0 is typically the wired Ethernet while en1 is the WiFi interface).

As an alternative, `netstat -i` will list all interfaces and will show you the IP addresses you have assigned to each of them.

Typically, when you have SSH daemon running on a box, it will listen on all available interfaces, ie. you can use any IP address that's configured on your machine to connect to that machine via SSH (this, obviously, subject to Firewall rules). If you're after what the OS calls a Primary interface and primary IP address, you can use the `scutil` command like this:

```
MacBook:~ scutil
> show State:/Network/Global/IPv4
<dictionary> {
  PrimaryInterface : en0
  PrimaryService : C0550F84-5C07-484F-8D62-C8B90DC977D8
  Router : 10.103.4.1
}
> show State:/Network/Interface/en0/IPv4
<dictionary> {
  Addresses : <array> {
    0 : 10.103.4.234
  }
  BroadcastAddresses : <array> {
    0 : 10.103.4.255
  }
  SubnetMasks : <array> {
    0 : 255.255.255.0
  }
}
```

Please note, that the above, even though is a command-line command, is also interactive (so you run `scutil` and then enter its own commands into it). The first `show` command tells you the name of the primary interface for the OS (i.e. this will be the one on top of the list in your System Preferences / Network Preferences window), as well as the IP address of your default router. The second `show` command takes `State:/Network/Interface/<ifname>/IPv4` argument (in this case, `en0`) and gives you the IP addresses assigned to it. You're looking for the address in the Addresses array, the other two entries are broadcast addresses and the netmasks.

Hope that helps, but if anything is not clear, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I wrote a quick script to get the IP your primary interface: `echo "show State:/Network/Interface/$(echo 'show State:/Network/Global/IPv4' | scutil | grep 'PrimaryInterface ' | sed 's/  PrimaryInterface : //')/IPv4" | scutil | pcregrep -Mo1 " Addresses : <array> {\n    0 : ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})"`

Answer (score 22):

To find your Mac's current internal IP address, run:

```
ifconfig -l | xargs -n1 ipconfig getifaddr
```

This is basically equivalent to `ipconfig getifaddr en0`, but more reliable! `en0` is not always the current network interface!

<sup>Thank you to @epylinkn in the comments of another answer for this hint. I'm posting it here so it's more visible; I initially missed it myself.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

To get the IP address of your computer facing the Internet, here is a
working receipe:

```
if=`netstat -nr | awk '{ if ($1 ~/default/) { print $6} }'`
ifconfig ${if} | awk '{ if ($1 ~/inet/) { print $2} }'
```

It should work even when you have multiple interfaces active,
even when you have interfaces you don't know which one is actually the
default gateway.

Comment: This gets the internal network IP address (eg: `192.168.0.*)`, not the external one exposed to the internet.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. Could you tell me on which version of the OS you are? Could you provide me the output of `netstat -nr | grep default` ?

Comment: This gets the IP of the interface that serves in/outbound traffic. If you're behind NAT, that will give your LAN address, not WAN address. But it can be useful for a lot of purposes, and it doesn't reach out for network.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, you can make a bash script with the following content which gives you your external IP address

```
#!/bin/bash    
wget -qO - http://ipecho.net/plain; echo
```

Comment: By default `wget` is not a part of macOS and needs to be installed from a non-Apple source.

Comment: Is the question macOS specific ? it is by default installed on many linux distributions.

Comment: This site is about Apple hardware and software, so macOS and iOS is presumed.

Comment: The default macOS command for this would be by using curl: `curl -s http://ipecho.net/plain; echo`

Answer (score 1):

This answer work on both mac and linux:

```
ifconfig | grep -E "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | head -1 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: Will list just for one interface, on not nessecarily the IP that is your _main_ route.