# How can I get the local IP address in macOS to use in a script?

Tags: macos, terminal, network, big-sur

I need to figure out the local IP address of Github runner, which uses macOS 11. I need this for my integration tests.

I tried:

```sh
LOCAL_IP=ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'
SERVER_URL="http://${LOCAL_IP}:5000"
```

However, this gave me just: `http://:5000`

Which is the correct command for this?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60160/how-can-i-find-my-ip-address-not-my-companys-router-but-my-local-machines, but the answers there are not easily useable in a script.

Comment: I know that there are many related questions, but I do not find any answer for a solution based on shell script.

Comment: Are these scripts running on the same machine as the server? If not is the server on a fixed machine?

Comment: I have a mono repository containing a python backend (flask) and a Flutter app. I've written end-to-end tests and now I want them to run in the pipeline. Therefore, I wrote a Github action file that starts the backend and after that the flutter integration tests. For this I need the IP of the backend, which runs locally on the MacOS Github runner.

Comment: I have two questions 1)Do you really need to write this as a script? For a one-off discovery it would be far easier to just look in the Network control Panel. 2) is this inside the same Mac? If so, then it's always 127.0.0.1.

Comment: 1) Yes. This is a Github runner which have no UI and I cannot connect to it. All I can do is executing a script with Github actions. 2) The app runs on an android virtual device. Therefore, 127.0.0.1 points to the virtual device, not to the mac where my backend is.

Comment: I honestly understood none of that;) so I'll step aside.

Comment: Then you need to look at the documentation of the app that provides the VM (e.g. virtualbox, docker ...) andsee how it sets up its network

Comment: I didn't find anything in the documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners#about-self-hosted-runners and here https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```bash
LOCAL_IP=ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

sets the variable `LOCAL_IP` to `ifconfig` to run an empty command, and sends the empty output of that empty command to the pipe built of `| grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'`. So `LOCAL_IP` is never set afterwards.

What you probably want to run is

```bash
LOCAL_IP=$(ifconfig | grep 'inet ' | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}')
```

which can be simplified to

```bash
LOCAL_IP=$(ifconfig | awk '/inet /&&!/127.0.0.1/{print $2}')
```

Unfortunately this will return two rows on Macs which are connected over both Ethernet and WLAN. So it's probably safer to use

```bash
LOCAL_IP=$(ifconfig | awk '/inet /&&!/127.0.0.1/{print $2;exit}')
```

which will pick the first network interface/IP address found.

Answer (score 11):

The local IP address can be obtained with the following command:

```
ipconfig getifaddr en0
```

or `en1`, depending on your Mac and your connection.

Comment: Does not work for me: `/Users/runner/work/_temp/f51fbf9d-2251-420a-ad21-c16451b2e107.sh: line 4: getifaddr: command not found`

Comment: @DarkMath The command is `ipconfig getifaddr en0`.

Comment: @benwiggy Yes I tried. But the Github runner does not know the command `getifaddr` as you can see in the error message above.

Comment: @DarkMath The command to run is `ipconfig`, `getifaddr en0` are the parameters.

Comment: RE: "or en1, depending on your Mac and your connection." --  Or it could be something else, as on my system it's currently `en7`.  While `en0` and `en1` at the typical, it really depends on what Mac one has and how it is setup to interface with the LAN.

Comment: This returns simply nothing for me. The other two solutions work, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option which may be useful to you.

This command will create a variable with the local IP address.

```
LOCAL_IP=$(osascript -e "IPv4 address of (system info)")
```

This command will return the local IP address stored in `$LOCAL_IP`

```
echo $LOCAL_IP
```

Comment: This is nice, not having to worry about the BSD Device Name of the network adapter. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Python without supplying an interface name:

```sh
python -c 'import socket; print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))'
```